# recaptcha on form submit not validating

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I've followed the other questions' answers on stackoverflow, but I can't seem to get this to work.

I have in the head of my document...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var onloadCallback = function() {
    grecaptcha.render('html_element', {
      'sitekey' : '6LfKyw4UAAAAANUnCAm33p-CyeoPJJNcURNteW2R'
    });
  };
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    //check google recaptcha has been added successfully
function checkvalid()
  var isCaptchaValidated = false;
var response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
if(response.length == 0) {
isCaptchaValidated = false;
toast('Please verify that you are a Human.');
} else {
isCaptchaValidated = true;
}


if (isCaptchaValidated ) {

}
  </script>
```

and then the submit button is as follows...

```
<button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="checkvalid()" >SIGN UP!</button>
```

I am a complete novice on javascript, and have probably done something very simple wrong, but when the button is clicked it completely ignores the recaptcha and inserts a record as it is supposed to.

Comment: You're missing your opening curly brace `{` for the function `checkvalid()` -- Might be the issue. Check your browser's JS console

Comment: thanks Wes, I added that  curly brace, and the strange thing is that the Google console is giving no errors at all. Any thoughts or ideas would be appreciated a great deal